# Include bar labels "inside" ggplot plot bar chart

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse

I need to put all the labels "inside" the bars of my ggplot.
I having problems because I need to group the variables and then include the labels inside the bars.

This is my code:

```
df <- structure(list(name = c("Player 1", "Player 2", "Player 3", 
    "Player 4", "Player 5", "Player 6", "Player 7", "Player 8", 
    "Player 9", "Player 10", "Player 11", "Player 12", "Player 13"
    ), pos = c("Lateral", "Lateral", "Central", "Central", 
    "Meio Campo", "Extremo", "Extremo", "Meio Campo", "Avancado", 
    "Meio Campo", "Avancado", "Meio Campo", "Lateral"), total = c(9263L, 
    10451L, 9845L, 9719L, 11650L, 10831L, 11143L, 8816L, 7666L, 9587L, 
    2703L, 2085L, 1282L)), row.names = c(NA, -13L), class = c("tbl_df", 
    "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

This is what I tried so far:

```
df %>% mutate(name = fct_reorder(name,total)) %>% ggplot(aes(pos, total,fill = pos, group = total,label = name)) +
    geom_col(show.legend = FALSE,
             position = position_dodge2(),width = .5) +
    geom_label(aes(group = name),color = "white",                   
               position = position_dodge2(width = .9),
               show.legend = FALSE) + coord_flip()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An option would be using `geom_text` and displaying the labels inside your bars. You can use the following code:

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% mutate(name = fct_reorder(name,total)) %>% ggplot(aes(pos, total,fill = pos, group = total,label = name)) +
  geom_col(show.legend = FALSE,
           position = position_dodge2(),width = .5) +
  geom_text(aes(group = name),color = "white",                   
             position = position_dodge2(width = 0.5),
             show.legend = FALSE, hjust = 1.2, size = 2) + coord_flip()
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

To move your labels inside the bars set the width for the dodging of the labels the same as the width of your bars and use `hjust=1` to align the labels to the right. Additionally with small bars I would suggest to reduce the font size and as a matter of taste remove the outline of the labels:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(forcats)

df %>%
  mutate(NOME = fct_reorder(NOME, TOTAL.DISTANCE)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(PLAYER.POSITION, TOTAL.DISTANCE, fill = PLAYER.POSITION, label = NOME)) +
  geom_col(aes(group = NOME),
    show.legend = FALSE,
    position = position_dodge2(), width = .5
  ) +
  geom_label(aes(group = NOME),
    color = "white", hjust = 1, label.size = 0,
    position = position_dodge2(width = .5),
    show.legend = FALSE, size = 8 / .pt, label.padding = unit(2, "pt")
  ) + 
  coord_flip()
```

[image]